# Why does x return a 5 if its zero and returns another expression multiplied by 5 if not?

Tags: java

I have a snippet of code that will help in creating the graph of an entered polynomial however, I do not understand why x1 has to be initiated this way

I've tried to deconstruct the line but I have come up with nothing, the graph would just display the wrong ticks if x1 returns anything else but the original code.

here is the line where getting x (which is a private int within a class to create the GUI) being initiated:

```
 mainPanel.x = (mainPanel.value.getText().isEmpty()) ? 0:
            Integer.parseInt(mainPanel.value.getText());
```

here is the line where I am confused in:

```
 int x1 = (mainPanel.x == 0) ? 5 : (int)
                        Math.sqrt(mainPanel.x * polynomial.getExponent()) * 5;
```

The getExponent method:

```
 public int getExponent(){
    // no negative polynomials
    int t = -1;
    for (Term term: listTerms){ //from  ArrayList<Term> listTerms = new ArrayList<>();
        if (t < term.getExponent())
            t = term.getExponent();
    }

    return t;
}
```

the getExponent just returns this.exponent within the Term class

basically creating the whole graph would look like this:

```
 GraphTest graph = new GraphTest(400, x1);
                graph.setLayout(null);
                graph.setPolynomial(polynomial);
                graph.setVisible(true);
                mainPanel.column2.add(graph);
                graph.setBounds(21, 23, 400, 400);
```

on the GraphTest class, the default constructor:

```
  public GraphTest(int size, double maxValue) {
    this.size = size;
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
}
```

Comment: The line you are confused about is an `if` statement as a one-liner. The `?`-operator divides the condition from the the possible results. If the expression before `?` evaluates to `true`, the first value will be taken (that's the one between `?` and `:`) and the second one otherwise. That means if `mainPanel.x == 0`, `x1` will get the value `5`, otherwise it gets the result of the calculation as its value. You have a similar operation in the initiialization of `mainPanel.x`, which will be `0` if there is no text entered in that panel.

Comment: Your question is unclear... Are you asking about the inline if condition ? then see the comment of deHaar. Or are you asking about the logic of using sqrt, getExponent, etc in the case where x != 0 ? Then either nobody can tell because it's specific to your job domain, or it's a math rule so it's off-topic here...

Comment: Are you asking about the `?` syntax or why x1 needs to be 5 if `mainPanel.x` is 0?

Comment: Note also that the (int) cast will happen before multiplication by 5.

Comment: @ Benjamin Urquhart, yes I do understand how the statement works but why specifically 5? and from what vincrichaud said I understand if the question is confusing and it seems very off-topic here as well

Comment: Have you tried another value than `5`? `1` maybe? `0` is obviously not suitable because the variable is used in multiplications that may result in `0` if one factor is `0`.

Comment: I have, but it would just give the wrong result in the graph